# Boolean sum with numpy finding matching pairs

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to find mirror images in a numpy array. In particular, `(x,y) == (y,x)` but I want to rule out tuples with identical values `(x,x)`.

Given a numpy array `pckList` with the size `(198L,3L)` containing floats.

I have the following code:

```
np.sum([x==pckLst[:,2] for x in pckLst[:,1]])
```

Which returns a given number, lets say 73

```
np.sum([x==pckLst[:,2] for x in pckLst[:,1]] and [x==pckLst[:,1] for x in pckLst[:,1]])
```

Returns a larger number, lets say 266.

Can someone please explain how this comes about?

I thought the first line returns True, when seen as tuples `(x,y) == (any,y)` and the second line returns only true when `(x,y) == (y,x)`.

Is this correct?

EDIT:
Further explaination:

`pckLst=[[ 112.066,    6.946,    6.938],
       [ 111.979,    6.882,    7.634],
       [ 112.014,    6.879,    7.587],
       [ 112.005,    6.887,    7.554],
       [ 111.995,    6.88,    6.88 ],
       [ 112.048,    6.774,    6.88 ],
       [ 111.808,    7.791,    7.566],
       [ 111.802,    6.88,    6.774]]`

Now I would like to find `[ 112.048, 6.774, 6.88 ]`, since `(6.88, 6.774) == (6.774, 6.88)`. However, `[ 111.995, 6.88, 6.88 ]` should not be considered a match.

Comment: Could you show an example input array and your desired output? It's hard to understand what you're trying to do here, or what it has to do with finding "mirror images".

Comment: @ali_m thanks for your input. please have a look at the edited post. Thank you.

Comment: What exactly do those "pairs" correspond to? I want you to show me an actual example of a `pckLst` array, and what the corresponding output should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than commenting on your code here is a simpler implementation

```
a=np.array([[1,1,10],[1,2,20],[2,1,30],[1,3,40],[2,3,50]])
xy= a[:,:2].tolist()
[[x,y,z] for [x,y,z] in a if [y,x] in xy and x!=y]

[[1, 2, 20], [2, 1, 30]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The arguments to "and" in your example are python-lists. The truth value of a list is True if it is not empty. Thats why you get a bigger sum in the latter case.
This will return the sum of elements with (x,y) == (y,x). It obviously only works if your just interested in the sum and not particular indices:

```
import numpy
pckLst = numpy.array([[ 112.066,    6.946,    6.938],
       [ 111.979,    6.882,    7.634],
       [ 112.014,    6.879,    7.587],
       [ 112.005,    6.887,    7.554],
       [ 111.995,    6.88,    6.88 ],
       [ 112.048,    6.774,    6.88 ],
       [ 111.808,    7.791,    7.566],
       [ 111.802,    6.88,    6.774]])

coords = pckLst[:,1:]
equal_ids = numpy.ravel(coords[:,:1] != coords[:,1:])
unequal_coords = coords[equal_ids]
flipped = numpy.fliplr(unequal_coords)
coords_tuple_set = set(tuple(map(tuple, unequal_coords)))
flipped_tuple_set = set(tuple(map(tuple, flipped)))

print coords_tuple_set
print flipped_tuple_set
# need to devide by two, because we get (x,y) and (y,x) by the intersection
print "number of mirrored points:", 
print len(coords_tuple_set.intersection(flipped_tuple_set))/2
```